# is there a way to load all rows in ag-grid before they're rendered?

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I have a grid with dynamic number of rows using SSRM.
when the rows are loaded to the page I'd like to have a button that marks all of them as "checked"/"selected".
I do this using looping with the grid's API `forEachNode` method.

the issue is that some rows aren't loaded until the user scrolls down to them, therefore they aren't marked as checked if the button was pressed before scrolling.

the only Idea I have is to hold a state if the button was clicked and if so mark these rows as "checked"/"selected" when the `PaginationChanged` event is fired, since it's fired on scrolling.
is there any way to avoid the overhead of managing this state and loading all of the rows of a single page, or to make sure that all of them will be marked as "checked"?

here's a portion of my code that's activated when the button is clicked:

*NOTE*: this code is in a different component than the component that hold's the grid.

```
toggleSelect(): void {
    this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
    if (this.isChecked) {
      this.params?.api?.forEachNode((node: RowNode) => {
        node.selectThisNode(true);
      });

      const event: any = {
        type: 'selectionChanged',
        api: this.params.api,
        columnApi: this.params.columnApi
      };

      this.params?.api?.eventService?.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    else {
      this.deselectAll();
    }
  }
```

Comment: SSRM is also called the infinite row model. From that perspective, why do you need to load all rows? The number of rows may be just huge.

Comment: @mashi I'm using pagination and I can assume that the number of rows in one page shouldn't be too big.
and I want all of the rows that are fetched from the server to the displayed page to be selected when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you have pagination and you want to load all rows on the current page. If that is the case, you can set equal values for `paginationPageSize` and `cacheBlockSize`, this will cause datasource request data for the whole page in one request.

Comment: I've actually done it, and I tried multiple custom sizes for both page size and cacheBlockSize, but I can see that until I scroll to the bottom rows they're not even in the cacheState.

also might be worth noting that I'm using row groups, (only one level).